# add http header to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http-headers

i'm trying to build custom zip files on demand and have found some code that seems to work fine
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/creating-zip-file-with-php.html

i've inserted the code in my wordpress template and the only thing is that the `header()`

have to be sent before the template is loaded

how can i do this with wordpress?

heres the code with the headers

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();            // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip";          // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){       // Opening zip file to load files
    $error .=  "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
}
foreach($post['files'] as $file){               
    $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file);          // Adding files into zip
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name)){
    // push to download the zip
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    readfile($zip_name);
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($zip_name);
}
```

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers

Answer (score 8):

Wordpress has a hook for this. Add the headers to the `send_headers` hook by calling the `add_action` function.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip";
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
    $error .=  "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
}
foreach($post['files'] as $file) {               
    $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file);
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name)){
    add_action( 'send_headers', 'my_headers' );
    readfile($zip_name);
    // put this somewhere or return it
    // so it can be retrieved later, otherwise
    // it might print before your headers
    // are sent
    unlink($zip_name);
}

function my_headers() {
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;
}
```

This will all need to go in a function in your `functions.php` file in your theme folder

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a hook that executes before Wordpress adds anything to the output. One such hook is "init"

```
function do_my_stuff_with_headers() {
    // ...
}
add_action( 'init', 'do_my_stuff_with_headers' );
```

Comment: Note: there is a [send_headers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers) hook for this purpose

Comment: The "init" action is wrong here. The correct hook would be at "template_redirect", so that you only affect the front end view of the site.

Comment: No, the correct action isn't `template_redirect`, it's `send_headers`, like @tobymackenzie said.

Answer (score 2):

There is a handy `wp_headers` filter which allows you to include custom headers using array `key` => `value` pairs.

With the filter, the header sending is handled for you at the appropriate time.

For this use case:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_headers', function( array $headers ) {
    $headers['Content-type'] = 'application/zip';
    $headers['Content-Disposition'] 'attachment';
    return $headers;
});
```

[Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/)