# Wordpress - How to use the PHP header() function

Tags: wordpress

I need to use PHP headers like `header( 'Location: http://location.com' );` or `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");` from my wordpress plugin but it won't seem to how. I know that they need to be used before the page header is called, so I tried using the init hook:

```
add_action('init', 'test');

function test() {
    header( 'Location: http://location.com' ) ;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: How didn't it work? Any Errors?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517548/add-http-header-to-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect any page then use wp_redirect() method.. OR if you want to set the specific headers to make the content downloadable.. use below sample..code...

Suppose your url is like.. http://example.com/download/data.csv

```
add_action('template_redirect','yoursite_template_redirect');
function yoursite_template_redirect() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/downloads/data.csv') {
        header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload",true,200);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        echo 'data';
        exit();
    }
}
```